# XML cannot resolve symbole when Java SDK is set in Intellij IDEA

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, sdk

When i add Java JDK 1.8 to my Project SDK my XML code is highlithed red and displays "Cannot resolve symbol". The image below shows how all my XML code looks like.

[image]

I do not know why this is happening at all.

Comment: did you try the usual File>Invalidate Caches  ... then Invalidate and Restart ?

Comment: yes, and that made no difference.